# creating multiple file using os python

Tags: python, linux, for-loop

Hi folks I am using ros noetic and i have to create 12 file name as x.bag and x ranging upto 12. code is following.

> 

```
import rospy
import os
for x in range(12): 
    cmd='rosbag record -o /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/rosbag/x.bag /web_cam --duration 5 '
    os.system(cmd)
```

how I get vlaue of x in cmd.

creating 12 file of 5sec duration using os.while having different name i am not able to acess value of x inside cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly. I think what you want is to run the following command 12 times (from 0 to 11):

```
import rospy
import os
for x in range(12): 
    cmd = f'rosbag record -o /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/rosbag/{x}.bag /web_cam --duration 5'
    os.system(cmd)
```

You probably want 1..12 which you can easily do with `{x + 1}`.

BTW, this is called a "[Literal String Interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)", aka f-string. Pretty handy.